# ctest pass on interruptions caused by timeouts and fail on run time errors that required a timeout

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, exit-code, ctest

for every executable that gets built the below lines are run. I need to differentiate between timeouts from run time errors eg aborts() and from executables that are never supposed to terminate on their own?

```
if ( ${_build_FOLDER} MATCHES "Tests" )

        add_test( NAME ${_build_TARGET} COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${_build_TARGET}> )
        set_tests_properties( ${_build_TARGET} PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 60 )
        set_tests_properties( ${_build_TARGET} PROPERTIES FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "[^a-z]Error;ERROR;Failed" )

    endif()
```

Is there maybe a way to do some error checking on the return code for example return code less than 0 would imply interruption but an abort would probably be return code 1.

I'm not utilising any ctest dashboard or ctest script tools, I am mildly confused by them and need some examples to better understand them I think.